# winexe not working on a local account

Tags: linux, windows-xp, samba, remote-access, remote-control

I have been trying to get winexe working.

I believe winexe is based heavily on samba. For comparisons sake, everything works as expected with a samba file transfer to the host:

```
smbclient --workgroup=. --user=Administrator%asdfasdf //10.50.3.126/ADMIN$ -c "put test"
Domain=[WINXP0001] OS=[Windows 5.1] Server=[Windows 2000 LAN Manager]
putting file test as \test (0.0 kb/s) (average 0.0 kb/s)
```

But winexe is having problems with the same host and local credentials:

```
winexe --workgroup=.  --user=Administrator%asdfasdf //10.50.3.126 "cmd /C hostname"
ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

But Domain credentials work fine:

```
winexe --user=mydomain/Administrator%asdfasdf //10.50.3.126 "cmd /C hostname"
winxp0001
```

I've tried winexe 1.0 and .9

My target host is a windows xp machine.